# Flutter: exporting file to phone storage

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to export a txt file as srt (which is written in plain text) in my app and it is working in the sense that I see srt's with the correct name in the specified folder but these files are 0B and I'm not sure where what is not fully working?

```cpp
  void add() async {
    fileName = _fileNameCon.text.toString();
    print("filename ---------> " + fileName);
    newSubFile(fileName);
    setState(() {
      _fileNameCon.clear();
      srt = "";
      subnumber = 1;
      stopWatch.reset();
    });
  }

  void newSubFile(String title) async {
    try {
      // this is an android specific directory
      Directory directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      final path = directory.path;
      File newSrt = await File('$path/' + title + ".srt").create();
      var writer = newSrt.openWrite();
      print("----attempting to write to $path/$title----");
      writer.write(srt);
      writer.close();
      print("----closing----");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should call writer.flush(); before writer.close();

Answer (score 0):

Imports

```
import 'dart:io'
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

Example:

```
Directory dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
final file = File(join('${dir.parent}/sub folder',"Output.srt"));
await file.writeAsString(subtitles)
```